# How to Download file using Qt5 with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

I need a very simple console application to FTP into the server and get some file , I try with QNetworkAccessManager , and it seems like not working and getting nothing.

Here is my code ,

**ftp.h**

```
    #ifndef FTP_H
#define FTP_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <qstring.h>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include "qdebug.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QObject>

class ftp
{
//    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ftp();

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;

private slots:
    void slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code);
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};

#endif // FTP_H
```

**ftp.cpp**

```
#include "ftp.h"
#include "QDebug"

#include <qstring.h>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include "qdebug.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QObject>

using namespace std;

ftp::ftp()
{
    qDebug() << "ZSS Server Program Running Now ...";

    QTextStream cin(stdin);
    QString username;
    QString password;
    QString ip;
    QString port;

    cout << "Username : ";
    username = cin.readLine();

    cout << "Password : ";
    password = cin.readLine();

    cout << "IP Address : ";
    ip = cin.readLine();

    cout << "Port Number : ";
    port = cin.readLine();

    QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("ftp");
    url.setHost("10.228.7.74");
    url.setPath("/try/hello.txt");
    url.setPort(21);
    url.setUserName("ftpTest");
    url.setPassword("ftpTest");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    //request.setUrl(url);

    qDebug() << url;

    //cout << "Downloading File...";

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    reply = manager->get(request);
    QByteArray buffer = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << buffer;

//    connect(reply , SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this,SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
//    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void ftp::slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)
{
    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
}

void ftp::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
//    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8");
//    QString all = codectoUniCode(reply->readAll());
//    cout >> all;
//    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

After I run my code , inside my folder , I can't see any file is there. So I qDebug() out all the response and buffer , I found that the buffer and response is empty , is there any part I was missing or doing other things wrong ? Can I get a simple example for this ??

Here is the console output screenshots,

[image: Output of code]

I qDebug() the buffer , but the buffer doesn't have anythings on it , I create this ftp local server by using 3CDaemon , and I was point to the correct folder and my ftp server is running , I can use command prompt to ftp inside and get the file , just can't make it by using Qt.

Please help me , this have been trouble me for couple of days..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

`QNetworkAccessManager::get` is an asynchronous function. You can use the `QNetworkReply` it returns to monitor the progress of the download, but isn't ready to read immediately. You have to wait until the `finished` signal is emitted (either by the `QNetworkAccessManager` or the `QNetworkReply`) before you can read data from it.

If you really want the download to be synchronous, you can spin your own local event loop until the download finishes. For example

```
QEventLoop loop;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
connect(&mgr, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);

QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(...);
loop.exec();
qDebug() << reply.readAll();
```